# Problems with a Class in Java

Tags: java, string, class, parsing, double

```
public class Location {
private String city;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public Location(String aCity, double aLatitude, double aLongitude)
{
    city = aCity;
    latitude = aLatitude;
    longitude = aLongitude;
}
void setLocation(String theCity)
{
    city = theCity.trim();
}
void setLatitude(double lat)
{
    latitude = lat;
}
void setLongitude(double long1)
{
    longitude = long1;
}
public String getLocation()
{
    return city;
}
public double getLatitude()
{
    return latitude;
}
public double getLongitude()
{
return longitude;
}
public String tooString()
{
    String result = String.format("City: %s (%1.3f; %1.3f)", city, latitude,longitude);
    return result;
}
```

Main program:

```
public class Hmwk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line=input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens;
        tokens = line.split("\t");
        String city=tokens[0];
        double lat=Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
        double longy=Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]); //Error
        Location loc=new Location(city,lat,longy);
        loc.tooString();

    }


}
```

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` noted in the main program which I don't quite understand.

Input is divided by tabs even if it doesn't look like it...

```
St. Joseph, MO  +39.76580   -94.85060
Shanghai,China  +31.23300   +121.45000
Kansas_City,KS     +39.11780    -94.64000
```

Comment: Is it possible that your file data is dirty e.g. instead of tab there is some other separator? That could cause `tokens[i]` to fail

Comment: I don't believe so, did I implement everything correctly?

Comment: Print out the data in your array so you can confirm you're getting exactly three things.  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens);`  You'll have to import `java.util.Arrays` to see it.  But, that should shed *some* light on what's going on.

Comment: I have duplicated this exactly and printed out all the contents of the arrays. They are all of lenght 1 because `tokens.split("\t");` splits them on a tab character that is not present. The ENTIRE line, therefore, is put into index 0 and it moves on.

Comment: Additionally your data isn't even formatted in clear lines like it would be if you were using tabs. I completely recreated this project with actual tabbed input and it works. Your input is flawed. I'm 100% sure of it.

Comment: @leigero So I implemented the class in the main program correctly? This is driving me nuts man.

Comment: Its fine, I'm not sure how big your input file is, but I'm absolutely certain that what you think are tabs, are just spaces. Test it, Just take the 3 lines you posted here... delete the spaces and press tab. Then run the program with the file containing only those 3 lines and you'll see it works.

Comment: @leigero finally found the problem with the data, but when it ran it didn't print out anything?

Comment: @user102817 I'll update my answer and explain that as well.

Comment: @leigero I figured it out, thanks for all the help man I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user102817 No problem. That's why we hang out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your String is:

```
St. Joseph, MO  +39.76580   -94.85060
```

You're splitting it on the tab locations, which there are none in that line. Your array, therefore is of length 1.

```
tokens[0] = St. Joseph, MO  +39.76580   -94.85060
tokens[1] // doesn't exist.
```

Additionally the input you've provided is also not formatted in a tabular way:

```
St. Joseph, MO  +39.76580   -94.85060
Shanghai,China  +31.23300   +121.45000
Kansas_City,KS     +39.11780    -94.64000
```

Notice the last line isn't properly lined up with the others? They would be if you were using hard tabs. Make sure you're not using spaces in lieu of tabs but are actually using the tab button (or equivalent character if data is formatted programmatically).

I recreated the entire project from your own code and got the same error you did. I deleted the spaces and replaced them with actual Tab characters and it works fine.

**EDIT After the data works it doesn't print**

This is a simple fix. You're calling the `toString()` method but that does you no good when you don't do anything with the String value returned to you.

Just make it:

```
System.out.println(loc.tooString());
```

Comment: "Input is divided by tabs even if it doesn't look like it..." - OP

Comment: @ylun I honestly believe the OP is mistaken. Just looking at the input, the data is not even in-line which it would be if they were using tabs. These are definitely spaces.

Comment: It is due to the formatting on SO, ask for the file if you do not trust the OP.

Answer (score 4):

This is a working example, you problem comes from the input.txt file. If one of the Tab character (\t) is missing (mistyped Space instead) then split() will return less elements then 3.

1- Make a test to check if there are actually 3 elements:

```
if (tokens.length >= 3) {
 String city=tokens[0];
 double lat=Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
 ...
}
```

2- Check your input.txt file for spaces or missing Tab characters.

3- You should use toString() in your class instead of tooString(). This method is meant for this purpose :)

Working Class:

```
public class Hmwk {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line=input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\t");
        if (tokens.length >= 3) {
          String city=tokens[0];
          double lat=Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
          double longy=Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
          Location loc=new Location(city,lat,longy);
          System.out.println(loc.toString());
       }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When you declared the array, `tokens[]`, you did not specify a size for it.

```
    String[] tokens;
    tokens = line.split("\t");
    String city=tokens[0];
```

So when you go and set `longy` to be `tokens[2]`, the `2` spot does not exist.

you should change the code to specify a size:

```
    String[] tokens = new String[*size*];
    tokens = line.split("\t");
    String city=tokens[0];
```

Cheers

Comment: the array is automatically filled in according to the contents of the `.split("whatever");` so that wouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: @leigero nice, I did not know this was possible.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't understand how this got up-voted. It is not only not answering the question, its just wrong information.

Answer (score 2):

In the code below you are assuming that line you read from file has 3 tokens separated by '\t' you will get a ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception when there are not enough tokens. You should check the size of token array before you run the code

```
tokens = line.split("\t");
if (tokens.length == 3){
    String city=tokens[0];
    double lat=Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
    double longy=Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any blank lines in your file? In that case I think it may be possible that it returns a zero length array, in which case the 0th element will not exist. The documentation for split leads to here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29)

To protect against that it's a good idea to wrap it in a check for the number of elements returned from the split:

```
if (tokens.length >= 3) {
    String city=tokens[0];
    double lat=Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
    double longy=Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]); //Error
    Location loc=new Location(city,lat,longy);
    loc.tooString();
}
```